# Python fnmatch, check exist file

Tags: python, recursion, filesystems, fnmatch

I have a task, I wanna check if exist special file *.part in directory.
If file exist do check again, if not, print "file was deleted".

I use os.listdir(), next for each file in lisdir, I use fnmatch(file, '*.part'),next again get lisdir and recursively involve same function.

When I'am deleting this file, fnmatch return "true". I can't understand... "why"?

Here my code:

```
import os, fnmatch

def func(filenames):
      for f in filenames:
            while fnmatch.fnmatch(f, '*.part'):
                  filenames = os.listdir("/home/gromov/Downloads/test/")
                  func(filenames)


if __name__ == "__main__":
      func(os.listdir("/home/gromov/Downloads/test/"))
      print("file was deleted")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you call your function `func` recursively, `f` in the first iteration never changes and `fnmatch` only checks the string and not, if the file exists.

Use `os.path.exists`:
    import os, fnmatch, time

```
def func(filenames):
    for f in filenames:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, '*.part'):
            # wait until deleted
            while os.path.exists(f):
                time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Task decided!

Answer (score 1):

You are using recursion, perhaps the list of files you get from os.listdir() returns the same files list every time and therefor you get a True returned before it is updated.

Try writing this in a none recursive way and make sure the list you retrieve from os.listdir() is not the same every iteration you do.

Comment: I get new list intro "while" and pass his in func(), and in debug i see that it's new list, but in for loop " f " again become last value.